# Old Pocket PC as monitor?

Tags: display, pocket-pc

I retired my beloved iPAQ 5400 series Pocket PC a few years ago and ever since then it has sat in a drawer. Alone. Unloved.

But perhaps there's a use for it? Has anyone seen software that might allow a cradled/docked Pocket PC to act as an additional monitor? I believe this is possible with the really new stuff, but how about for the old units. I think my iPAQ is running PPC 2003.

Any thoughts?

Would be nifty to have a little twitter or IM app window running on it off to the side of my main monitor(s).

Comment: Great question mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a program called [Innobec SideWindow](http://www.pocketgear.com/en_US/html/display_product.jsp?id=prod5641205) that will allow you to extend your display to any kind of PocketPC device. I don't know what the support is for it nowadays, but at least it may prompt you to do some additional searching online for similar apps.

Comment: "[...] but at least it may prompt you to do some additional searching online for similar apps."  Ouch dude. Have to confess, while not explicitly expressed, I was hoping for real world suggestions not "Go  google" responses. That aside, I reckon I'll try the trial on SideWindow :-)

Comment: Not meant to be an ouch, only a "here's what I've found in a cursory attempt, so there's hope out there" type response since there hadn't been much response initially to the question and I was curious myself. 8^D